# « Pas de courant électrifié. Désolé. » : lexique et formulation ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, négation, régionalismes, style-de-rédaction

Sur la porte d'une salle de bain on a collé une feuille de papier sur laquelle est indiqué :

> Pas de [courant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/courant/1) [électrifié](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9lectrifi%C3%A9). Désolé.

Pendant un moment on se demande si on est au bon endroit mais il ne fait aucun doute. Et on est au Québec.

- Cet emploi de *courant électrifié*, s'agit-il d'un régionalisme, d'un emprunt/calque (de l'anglais ? de quel type), d'une [tautologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tautologie) courante tributaire de l'impact de l'[électrification](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9lectrification/1) au lexique, est-ce vieilli... ?
- Pourquoi préférerait-on couramment employer dans un tel contexte une tournure avec l'adverbe de négation [*pas*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pas/0) plutôt qu'avec un substantif qui en tienne lieu, comme [*panne*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/panne/2) ; pourquoi l'une ou l'autre serait plus claire, plus usuelle lorsque réduite à un « avertissement » comme ici ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

À défaut de courant électrifié, j'espère qu'il y a quand même de l'eau mouillée, dans cette salle de bain.

Vu à quel point `"courant électrifié"` est rare sur le web ([Google](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22courant+%C3%A9lectrifi%C3%A9%22) trouve « About 140 results » et s'arrête au bout de 29 sans compter ceux qu'ils considère comme doublons, [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22courant+%C3%A9lectrifi%C3%A9%22&ia=web) n'en trouve que 5), ce n'est manifestement pas du tout idiomatique. C'est une erreur que la personne qui a écrit ce papier n'est pas la première à faire, mais pas loin. Sur le web je ne vois que deux types de résultats qui ne sont pas clairement des faux positifs (avec une ponctuation entre les deux mots), des erreurs de numérisation, ou des suites de mots bout à bout qui n'ont pas de sens (des anti-anti-spam probablement) :

- Une [entreprise](http://www.bodacc.fr/annonce/telecharger/EBODACC-A_20090165_0001_p000.pdf) qui déclare comme activité « Production exploitation et commercialisation de toutes forces d’énergies
  renouvelables et notamment de courant électrifié ». Et même là il y a peut-être un problème de saisie ou de numérisation, en particulier *forces* devrait être *formes*, donc ce n'est pas clairement volontaire.
- Des fanfics ([« Un courant électrifié jailli brusquement du corps sans vie, rattrapant le second qui mit encore moins de temps à décéder »](http://warcraft-crusade.forumactif.org/t293-vae-victis-pv-vol-ajan-and-uriel), [« Un courant électrifié sortit des mains de Ringo et heurta le sol trempe »](https://www.fanfic-fr.net/fanfics/Animes-Mangas/N/Naruto/Le-Renouveau/46436/248135.html) dont je conteste la qualité littéraire et l'orthographe.

Bref, cette personne voulait dire « pas de courant électrique ».

« Panne de courant » sous-entend qu'il y a un problème qui va être réparé, par exemple un pylône renversé par le vent ou un fusible qui a sauté. C'est une [*panne*³](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/panne) : un « arrêt momentané accidentel et subit du fonctionnement » (B.1.a), une « interruption, coupure accidentelle » (B.1.b). « Pas de courant (électrique) » n'a pas ce sous-entendu que l'absence de courant est un défaut qui va être réparé. Ce peut être un propriétaire qui sait que son installation électrique est en mauvais état et n'a pas l'intention de la réparer.

Ou ce peut être un non-francophone qui a fait de son mieux pour exprimer l'idée « panne d'électricité » avec seulement de vagues souvenirs de français.

Comment: Merci ! C'était une note manusc. à halte routière à quelque part sur Jean Lesage et seule une des deux salles de bain était ainsi affectée. Langue seconde peut-être... Par ailleurs même si la collocation a attiré mon attention elle ne me surprend pas beaucoup, je la trouve orale et archaïsante, un peu comme si je disais _voiture motorisée_, genre de jargon traduit d'une loi par exemple. Par ailleurs l'eau a un courant, et il y avait l'eau courante néanmoins. Peut-être qu'on voulait dire quelque chose en évitant de dire autre chose. Merci !

Comment: @Dignitéveutdire... Il y a une salle de bain dans une halte routière ? Ah, des toilettes sur une aire de repos ? (Ici, une salle de bain, ça a une baignoire, à la rigueur une douche mais dans l'immobilier on dit « salle d'eau » s'il n'y a pas de baignoire.) Ah, le québecois, parfois on ditrait du français, et parfois non...

Comment: Davantage le Québécois que voici que le [québécois](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8361675), quoique souvent le québécois aussi ! Parfois j'hypercorrige à l'écrit et ça peut donner ce genre de lexique qui se voulait plus régulier mais on se ramasse dans le champ. Tout simplement impayable. Par ailleurs l'_aire de repos_ bien ça j'avais vu wikipédia discuter de la différence de terminologie, mais j'ai déjà vu ici il me semble _aire de repos pour camionneur_, c'est le même concept mais on y dort aussi j'imagine. Merci !